# Проблема с парсингом jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В общем, стоит задача спарсить данные заголовков новостей и привязать к заголовкам ссылку на новости с сайта. Новости заключены в контейнер news, а заголовки(краткое описание) заключены в теге a с атрибутом href (В ссылку в общем). При парсинге выдаёт полностью весь контейнер news включая сами новости и заголовки общим текстом. Вот фрагмент кода, а так же фрагмент html кода:

```
     class ParseText extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String str = " ";
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
                Elements elements = document.select("desc");
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return str;

        }
    }
    class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String,String>>
 {

     @Override
     protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
         HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
         try {
             Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://ktits.ru").get();
             Elements elements = document.select("div[class=news]");
             for(Element element:elements) {

             Elements elements1 = element.select("div[class=title]");
             hashMap.put(element.text(), elements1.attr("a:href"));
            }

         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return hashMap;
     }
 }
```

Фрагмент html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто когда вы используете селектор `"div[class=news]"` вы получаете список `Elements`, который содержит только один `Element`, а когда используете `"div[class=title]"`, то получаете список из 7ми, и в коде пытаетесь впихнуть всё это дело одним put'ом.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://ktits.ru").get();

Elements elements = document.select("div[class=news]").get(0).getElementsByTag("a");
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    hashMap.put(element.getElementsByClass("title").text(), element.attr("href"));
                }
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли, а что нибудь поменялось бы если бы использовал .firts();  при div[class=title] и брал бы не elements, а element?

Comment: Вот структура тэгов `<div class="news"><a href=""><div><div class="img" style=""></div><div class="text"><div class="date"><div>2019-02-27</div></div><div class="title"></div><div class="desc"></div></div></div></a></div>`, если вы выполняете `select("div[class=title]")`, то этот элемент не будет содержать тэга `a`, и `value` ассоциативного массива соответственно попадёт пустая строка.

Comment: Доброго времени суток ещё раз, появилась новая проблема. При нажатии на ссылку приложение крашится, по логам видно что он пытается перейти но не хватает доменного имени в начале. Пытался приплюсовать доменное имя http://ktits.ru/ к ссылке, тогда выводит просто пустое окно. Сделал вывод log.i никакого сообщения не выводит...

Comment: Добрый, сложно что-то сказать не видя исполняемого кода, закройте этот вопрос(на него же ответили?), оформите новый с логом ошибки и кодом, где она воспроизводится.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.